# " 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'Attribute_name' " while perfroming test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, view

The test class :

```
class UpadtePadlockTest(TestCase):
    username = "testusername"
    email = "testuser@name.com"
    username2 = "testusername2"
    email2 = "testuser2@name.com"

    def test_update_padlock(self):
        User = get_user_model()    
        user1 = User.objects.create_user(
            self.username, self.email ,
        )
        user2 = User.objects.create_user(
            self.username2, self.email2 , user_locked_with=user1
        )
        user1.user_locked_with=user2
        
        new_padlock= PadLock.objects.create(start_date=datetime.date(datetime.today()),motto_field="Jodo is my motto",creator=user1,modifier=user2)
        
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('edit_padlock'),
        {'start_date':datetime.date(datetime.today()),
            'motto_field':"Jodo is not my motto"})
        
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,302)

        new_padlock.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(new_padlock.motto_field,"Jodo is not my motto")
```

The view that is causing the problem

```
def edit_padlock(request):
    # dictionary for initial data with
    # field names as keys
    context ={}
    user = request.user 
# this is the attr that the AnonymousUser is lacking "user_locked_with"
# So filtering users by this attr is not possible 
    user2 = CustomUser.objects.get(username= user.user_locked_with)
    
    # fetch the object related to passed id
    try:
        obj = PadLock.objects.get(modifier=request.user)
    except Exception:
        obj = PadLock.objects.get(creator=request.user)
    
    # pass the object as instance in form
    form = PadLockForm(request.POST or None, instance = obj)
 
    # save the data from the form and
    # redirect to detail_view
    if form.is_valid():
        
        user.lock_published = True 
        user2.lock_published = True
        user.save()
        user2.save()
        form.save()
        try:
            padlock = PadLock.objects.get(modifier=request.user)
            padlock.active_state = True 
            padlock.save()
        except:
            padlock = PadLock.objects.get(creator=request.user)
            padlock.active_state = True 
            padlock.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
 
    # add form dictionary to context
    context["form"] = form
 
    return render(request, "edit_padlock.html", context)
```

My Custom User :

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    age= models.PositiveBigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    lock_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lock_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=7,validators=[MaxValueValidator(7),MinValueValidator(0)])
    user_is_sender = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_is_reciever = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_locked_with = models.CharField(max_length=125,null=True,blank=True)
    lock_exist = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    lock_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The blog post aka the PadLock model :

```
class PadLock(models.Model):
    start_date =  models.DateField()
    lock_nature = models.TextField(max_length=5,choices=lock_natures,default=story)
    motto_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    story_field = models.TextField(max_length=20000,blank=True ,validators=[MinLengthValidator(4000)])
    active_state= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    creator = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(),related_name="creator",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    modifier = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(),related_name="modifier",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("padlock_detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

I was writing the test for a certain functionality which is modifying a blog post and publishing the post which is referred to as a "padlock" in my code.  Should I override the AnonymousUser class ? is there anyway to avoid any unnecessary complications ?

Comment: please specify which line is emitting the error. your code doesn't even show anything with `anonymous user` or `Attribute_name`   Where is the test? we need to see all the code that is pertinent to this running test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u/Quantra2112 answered the problem on r/djangolearning

> You are getting the user from the request and when that user is not
> authenticated it will be an instance of AnonymousUser. So you can use
> the login method on the test client:
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login
>
> You should then also protect your view with the login_required
> decorator:
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator
>
> If you don't want to restrict the view to authenticated users I would
> look for a solution using sessions instead of trying to do anything
> with the AnonymousUser class.
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions
> "

The solution is using the log in method on the client and adding the decorator @login required on the edit_padlock view.